# The second Hardy Littlewood conjecture is false - a question

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function. The second Hardy- Littlewood conjecture states that $\pi(x+y) \leq \pi(x) + \pi(y)$, $x,y \geq 2$.

Assume that this last statement is true. Then, by the Subadditive Limit theorem (aka Fekete's Lemma),
we have that $\lambda = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \pi(x)/x$ exists and satisfies $-\infty \leq \lambda <\infty$.

Now, by the Prime Number Theorem, we have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \pi(x) \log(x)}{x} = 1$, and so, that $\lambda = +\infty$. Hence, a contradiction.

If anyone could please offer some advice, I would be very grateful. I cannot see any problem with this, at first instance. I know hardly anything about the background on this conjecture and I just came up with this, but I cannot think of any problem with this argument. The Fekete Lemma I refer to is quite standard, see e.g. Hille 1948, Theorem 6.6.1. For the prime number theorem one can see the wikipedia article.

Many thanks

Comment: PNT implies that $\lambda = 0$, not $\lambda = \infty$, no?

Comment: PNT says $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$, so $\pi(x)/x \sim 1/\log x \to 0$